# How to formally conclude that $ x^2-(\zeta_9+\zeta^{-1}_9)x+1 $ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_9+\zeta^{-1}_9)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

To find the degree of extension $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_9):\Bbb Q(\zeta_9+\zeta^{-1}_9)]$, I need to formally conclude that $ x^2-(\zeta_9+\zeta^{-1}_9)x+1 $ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_9+\zeta^{-1}_9)$. And then I got stucked. Could someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\zeta$ is not real. (Nor is $\zeta^{-1}$.)

Comment: I do know it. But how to formally prove that the polynomial has no real root? I tried quadratic formula but it does not seem to work.

Comment: The quadratic has two roots, And only two roots! Neither is real.

Comment: And the quadratic formula does work, it gives you (as $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$) roots $\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}\pm\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}$ which are just $\zeta, \zeta^{-1}$.

Comment: I need an $i$ before the $\sin$. Apologies.